# Hide DIV depending on text inside another DIV in DOM with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need to hide a DIV depending on userroles. I have no variable to use from these userroles, except text inside a title tag.

html:

```
<title>admin</title>
```

If admin then hide the DIV for an example

```
<div class="demo"></div>.
```

I can only use Vanilla Javascript.

Update: This hides the div, but shows it for a blink at pageload:

```
$('document').ready(
function() {
function _title(){ 
if(document.title=="admin"){
document.getElementById('demo').style.display="none";
}
}
window.onload=_title;
});
```

Comment: What div? No div included in your code.

Comment: You are aware that if you hide the div it can still be found using inspect element.... so if you plan on having administration data on the page and you "hide" the div it will still exist on the page but not visible for those who don't know how to right click > inspect element or view source...

Comment: Included a demo div in description. Yes. im aware of this. the div is visible anyhow at the moment for any userroles, but cant be accessed so this isnt a problem. Thanks for the heads up anyhow.

Comment: I have edited my answer, this should fix the "blink" issue on page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay well this should answer your question.
This will set style none for element with the ID of demo.

```
function _title(){
if(document.title=="admin"||document.title=="admin1"){
    document.getElementById('demo').style.display="block";
}
}
window.onload=_title;
```

If you to use `class` rather than `id` to allow this function to work with multiple elements....

```
function _title(){
if(document.title=="admin"){
    var DemoClass = document.getElementsByClassName('demo');
    for(var i=0; i<DemoClass.length; i++) {
        DemoClass[i].style.display="block";
    }
}
}
window.onload=_title;
```

If this answers your question, marking your question as answered would be appreciated.

Simple add this to your page 
For `id`

```
<style type="text/css">
#demo{display:none;}
</style>
```

For `class`

```
<style type="text/css">
.demo{display:none;}
</style>
```

---- Titles that contain the word `Admin` ----

For `Class`

```
function _title(){
    var allow = document.title.search("admin");
if(allow>-1){
    //Set display for demo element
    var DemoClass = document.getElementsByClassName('demo');
    for(var i=0; i<DemoClass.length; i++) {
        DemoClass[i].style.display="block";
    }
}}
```

For `id`

```
function _title(){
    var allow = document.title.search("admin");
if(allow>-1){
    //Set display for demo element
document.getElementById('demo').style.display="block";
}}
```

Comment: Oh thanks! that was interesting. works great. Only thing is that I can see the div for a minute on pageload.. Adding the script im using to my inital question, might be something im doing.

Comment: This works perfect. What a great answer. Javascript is frickign awesome!

Comment: Hmm. Would it be possible to reverse the script? seems like all of my userroles have the same text inside the title tags. So Hide it for  everyone except for an example admin and admin1? @NewToJS

Comment: You can change it to anything you want. Just edit 
if(document.title=="admin")
for example, if(document.title=="admin1") <-- will only show the elements if the title is set to admin1

Comment: Hmm. It seems to hide it for everyone. My titletags does have more then the text admin inside it, does it have to be the full string?

Comment: Please check edited answer for allowing titles admin and admin1

Comment: Problem is that both title have the same strings, its about 5-6 words, where the different is admin, and admin1, which is placed in the middle of the string. If i use the full string it works, but i need ti target a single word in the string

Comment: Please review the updated answer. This will be my last edit on this answer as the question seems to be growing and coming away from the original question in hand.

Comment: Sorry for the extended query. It does works perfect now! thank you so much!